# -bash: ./my_file: cannot execute binary file:Exec format error, but my architecture and elf matches

Tags: bash, 64-bit, 32-bit, arm, binary

I am trying to run binary file on Odroid-C2 with `ubuntu64-16.04.3-minimal-odroid-c2-20171005` OS. This file has 777 privileges and is compiled for ARM.

```
# ls -l my_file
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 136409 Sep 30 13:17 my_file

#pwd
/home

#file my_file
my_file: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1, statically linked, not stripped

#uname -a
Linux odroid64 3.14.79-116 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 26 01:19:06 BRT 2017 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

When I try to run it (`./my_file`), I get an error:
**-bash: ./my_file: cannot execute binary file:Exec format error**

I am aware that my binary file is 32bit and my Ubuntu is 64bit, so I followed [this tutorial](https://forum.armbian.com/topic/4764-running-32-bit-applications-on-aarch64/) to add new architecture. This did not help, same error is occuring.

I also searched for another solutions, but it seems that the only problem occuring with this error is unmatching architecture. I am quite sure this is not my problem - elf is ARM, so is Odroid. I used to run similar binary files on this Odroid before, so I am really confused now.

Can you, please, help me find my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM`

This is a 32bit ARM executable file designed for the 32-bit ARM infrastructure environments (armhf, armel, arm64 when you have the 32bit ARM libs)

> `aarch64`

Your architecture is 64-bit ARM.  Specifically, `aarch64` chips *ONLY* support the ARMv8 A64 instruction set, and **do not** support A/T32 runtime instruction sets like this binary needs <sup>1</sup>.

So the system's complaining is actually valid - the 32-bit ARM executable has an invalid ELF header for a 64-bit `aarch64` environment which can't execute A/T32 instruction sets.

---

<sup>1</sup>  Supposition based upon https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/arm/aarch64 which states:

> The AArch64 execution state was introduced with the ARMv8 ISA for machines executing A64 instructions. A machine in AArch64 can only execute A64 instructions and cannot execute A32 or T32 instructions.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Do you know about any option how can I run this binary (maybe recompile binary somehow, or force Odroid to use A/T32 instructions? Is this possible?)

Comment: @catalex both questions would have to be sent to oDroid or the people that made the oDroid port sorry